# How to Get records on Modal Box through id? (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, bootstrap-modal

How can I get the complete message on modal box through message_id?

There is a button with named "Open Complete Message." When I click on that button a Modal Box come up with demo content, any simple tutorial? That can show how I can make it dynamic?

I'm a newbie, and it would be appreciated if you guys let me know any non-complicated way.

Thankyou!

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: Yes, but failed.

Comment: just update your code here

Comment: Read on [bootstrap modal](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp)

Comment: Can't understand, how to post multiple codes.

Comment: @Rafiq appreciate your help, but that's not I was talking about.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have four separate things going on here: the button, the modal, the jQuery and the CodeIgniter controller/model functions.  In theory, you will want to do something like below.  In practice, you will likely need to adapt your jquery and php accordingly.

**THE BUTTON**

The button will use the *data-id* attribute, so that you can store the message_id you mentioned.  You will likely populate that with dynamic PHP.

```
<button type="button" id="messageButton" class="btn btn-success" title="Open Complete Message" data-id="123">Open Complete Message</button>
```

**THE MODAL**

Not much to explain here.  Clicking the button will trigger this modal (via the jQuery below).  In theory, the modal would be empty by default.  The message/info inside the modal will be populated by the jQuery/PHP functionality.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="messageModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="messageLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="messageLabel"></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**THE JQUERY**

```
$('#messageButton').on('click', function() {

    var theMessageID = $(this).attr("data-id");
    var theURL = '/messages/getmessage/';  //adjust according to your site/setup

    $.post(url,
        {
            MessageID: theMessageID,
        },
        function (data, status) {
            if (status == 'success') {

                 // loop through data
                $.each(data, function() {

                    $('#messageLabel').text(this[1]);  // message title
                    $('#messageModal .modal-body').html(this[2]);  // the actual message

                });

                $('#messageModal').modal('show');

            } else {
                alert('No message available');
            }
        }
    });//end post
});
```

**THE CONTROLLER**

This assumes you have a controller named Messages with a getmessages function, as well as a Messages model with a function named get_message.

```
public function getmessage()
{
    // double checking
    if ( $this->input->post('MessageID') && is_numeric($this->input->post('MessageID')) ) {

        $this->load->model('Messages_model');
        $theMessage = $this->Messages_model->get_message($this->input->post('MessageID'));

        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode( $theMessage );
    }
}
```

Hope this helps the cause.  But please, post what you have tried.